# how to update badge app number while app is in foreground in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to update badge app number while the app is in foreground(opened). I'm using Flutter App Badger plugin 1.2.0, the code:

```
static Future _onMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
int? badgeCount = 23;
if (badgeCount != null)  {
  FlutterAppBadger.isAppBadgeSupported();
  FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(badgeCount);
}
```

in background or if the app is closed, the code works, but in foreground is executing, but is not updating the app icon.

any ideas are welcome

Comment: Where you call func _onMessageHandler? and you are testing on iOS or Android?